# Change Color of SVG mobile hamburger icon on Hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to change the mobile hamburger menu icon to fit the color of my logo when the mouse is over -

```css
.menu-hamburger:hover {
  fill: #FFB400!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> 

<svg class="menu-hamburger">
   <use xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"></use>
</svg> 

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
       <symbol id="menu-hamburger" class="menu-hamburger" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; color:#FFF;">
            <rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            <rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            <rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
       </symbol>
   </defs>

</svg> 

</a>
```

but still no luck

Comment: Can you make an image of what happened because the color changing worked for me.

Comment: it goes from white to red which is the default color from the theme- even with fill: #FFB400!important;

Comment: The color change is working for me as well.

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign you need to call svg.class to make it change look below code.

Comment: Color change works fine for me. What browser and OS are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```css
svg.menu-hamburger :hover {
      fill: #FFB400!important;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#"> 

<svg class="menu-hamburger">
   <use xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"></use>
</svg> 

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
       <symbol id="menu-hamburger" class="menu-hamburger" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; color:#FFF;">
            <rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            <rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            <rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
       </symbol>
   </defs>

</svg> 

</a>
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is needed because the original code works fine for me.

Comment: Don't ask me. I'm not sure why it doesnt work for him. but this is another way you can really do it. I'm just aswering that might work for him.

Comment: Sorry, I meant could you give some explanation of why this is different?

Comment: i put svg.class, he have .class only, so it really specifies that his calling the class of the svg. Thats the difference.

Comment: This worked- But i honestly don't know why the other scripts did not work first- All i can think is there is a jQuery code that was forcing that color, an unclosed HTML tag, or another css issue

Comment: I just had the same issue on one of the website I took over and i've learned from it that specifying what you really want to call is powerful specially if you are bumping into something that you dont have any idea where is it. So yes thats probably whats going on on your end. Glad it works. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

When using `<use xlink:href="#"` , the SVG content falls into the `DOM shadow` and the styling result depends on the style hierarchy of the external, internal CSS style sheet, SVG presentation styles
What will be the result of the struggle of these styles is not always easy to foresee..

Therefore, in the adjacent answer, the rule `fill: #FFB400!important;`
But this is a ***very bad practice*** that can break the rest of the layout.

The style hierarchy can be seen in the image below from the article: By Sara Soueidan [Styling SVG  Content with CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/)

[image]

**Computed Styles** has the biggest weight.
Therefore, it is most reliable to use CSS variables for CSS styling.

```css
.menu-hamburger {
margin:1em;
}
#u1,#u2 {
 fill:black;
 
 }
 #u1:hover {
 --primary-color: red;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
  #u2:hover {
 --primary-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#"> 

<svg class="menu-hamburger" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
   <use id="u1" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"  ></use>
</svg> 
<svg class="menu-hamburger" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
   <use id="u2" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"  ></use>
</svg> 

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
         <symbol   class="menu-hamburger">
             
          <g id="menu-hamburger" style="fill: var(--primary-color, black)">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
            <rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            <rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            <rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
            </g>
       </symbol>
  
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

By applying CSS variables you can implement multi-color icons

```css
.menu-hamburger {
margin:1em;
}
#u1,#u2 {
 fill:black;
 
 }
 #u1:hover {
 --primary-color: green;
 --second-color: gold;
 --third-color: red;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
  #u2:hover {
  --primary-color: purple;
 --second-color: greenyellow;
 --third-color: dodgerblue;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#"> 
    <svg class="menu-hamburger" width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
       <use id="u1" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"  ></use>
    </svg>  
</a>
<a href="#"> 
    <svg class="menu-hamburger" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
       <use id="u2" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"  ></use>
    </svg> 
</a>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
       <defs>
         <symbol   class="menu-hamburger">
             
          <g id="menu-hamburger" style="fill: var(--primary-color, black)">
             <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
            <rect y="1" width="16" height="2" style="fill: var(--primary-color)"></rect>
            <rect y="7" width="16" height="2" style="fill: var(--second-color)"></rect>
            <rect y="13" width="16" height="2" style="fill: var(--third-color)"></rect>
            </g>
       </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I changed the `<a>` to a `<button>` because the action of clicking it is not navigating somewhere but opening a menu. It has the same properties. Controlling the width and the height of the menu is done using the `button#menu-hamburger svg` selector together with the fill color. So, now using a similar selector (`button#menu-hamburger:hover svg`) for hover the menu changes color without problem. I added the hover to the button so that you also "hover" when the pointer is in between the bars in the hamburger menu.

```css
button#menu-hamburger {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

button#menu-hamburger svg {
  fill: #000;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

button#menu-hamburger:hover svg {
  fill: #FFB400;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" display="none">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="menu-hamburger" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect>
      <rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect>
      <rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<button id="menu-hamburger"> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#menu-hamburger"/>
  </svg>
</button>
```